# How to scroll to an HTML element without an ID

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

im trying to scroll to a specific element inside a site which is embedded in a iframe component. I have tried with scrolling to a concrete possition with 'x' and 'y' but this is not a viable solution since its hardcoded and static, resulting in problems on lower or higher screen resolutions.
I saw that there is a way to scroll to an element based on id:

```
document.getElementById("divFirst").scrollIntoView();
```

This is good and all but the elements which im trying to access do not have id and are not distinguishable by class either.

[image]

There are several other components looking exactly like this one, same classes, same structure and i cant modify them since they are from an outer source!

Is there any way to scroll to such an element?

Comment: How about CSS selectors with [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)?

Comment: If you know the position of the element you want to scroll to you can use it as an index. `document.getElementsByClass("some-class")[index];`

Comment: *I saw that there is a way to scroll to an element based on id* <-- That's not a way to scroll based on an `id`. `scrollIntoView` only needs an element reference - it doesn't care how you got that reference, so use `querySelector` and locate the element based on some other characteristic, like its position or CSS classes that it has (or both).

Comment: This is infact true yes, but the elements inside the frame are not in the same DOM and are not detected. I can get an element from my page and log it, whenever i get an element from the iframe's page i log null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of all the answers posted in this thread i have managed to find how to fix it.
The most important thing here was that the element was in a different DOM not my current, since im trying to locate an element in a embedded website (Website from the iframe html element). This is my solution:

```
//locate the frame
var iframe = document.getElementById("frameId");
//get the inner DOM
element = iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelector('#headerDiv > div.col-sm-4 > h1');
//and then just do a basic scroll
element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end'});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the query selector and specifying the elements selector path as given to you by your browser:

resulting in something like this

[#question > div > div.postcell.post-layout--right > div.mb0 > div > div.post-signature.owner.grid--cell > div > div.user-action-time > span](https://gyazo.com/bf5c294ed164208c19f0c3e0374505fb)

Comment: This is infact true yes, but the elements inside the frame are not in the same DOM and are not detected. I can get an element from my page and log it, whenever i get an element from the iframe's page i log null